# Как узнать с какого сервера запущена хранимая процедура

Tags: sql-server

Имеются 3 физических сервера MS SQL 2008R2, условно назовем их Основной, Тестовый и Вспомогательный. Вспомгательный привязан к Основному и Тестовому как связанный сервер. На Вспомогательном создана хранимая процедура, которая вызывается из Основного или Тестового так:
`EXEC [Вспомогательный].[База].[dbo].[Процедура]`
Так вот, мне надо в процедуре узнать из какого сервера запущена процедура: из Основного или Тестового.
Пробовал внутри процедуры получить имя удаленного сервера так: `SELECT @@REMSERVER`, но получаю NULL.
Рассматривал вариант с передачей параметра в процедуру, содержащего имя сервера (`@@SERVERNAME`), но не хотелось бы вводить еще один дополнительный параметр. Но если это единственный путь, то придется сделать так.
Тестирую на SQL Server Managmet Studio.
В какую сторону посоветуете копать?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте имя хоста:

```
select @@hostname;
```

Comment: Хм... такой вариант не рассматривал, спасибо ). Только так:  
`SELECT HOST_NAME()`

Comment: Ну может и так - я давно уже не кодил под мускулом :)

Answer (score 1):

Вызывать с разных серверов от имени разных пользователей и потом смотреть кто вызвал с помощью `SUSER_NAME()`

Comment: @TheDoctor является ответом на вопрос. Только автор как-то не уверен в своих силах, поэтому задал слишком много вопросов в теле ответа :) Поправил эту оказию :)

Comment: @ReinRaus, Быть может, быть может...

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно передавать в качестве параметра в хранимку информацию о текущем сервере из `@@SERVERNAME`

Comment: Да, спасибо, рассматривал такой вариант. Но не хотелось бы вводить дополнительные параметры.

Comment: По идее все что будет вызываться из хранимки Вспомогательного сервера будет выполнятся в его контексте и о сервере на котором он залинкован он ничего не знает.